# Incorporate range within a cell to range formula in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

In cells A1 and A2, I have a concatenate formula that produces X1:X2 and Y1:Y2 respectively, where in both the letter and numerical values are dependent on certain formulas in the worksheet.

In VBA, I wish to sort out the describe ranges in A1 and A2 separately. I tried the following formula, but it didn't work:

```
Sub Sort()
    Dim myrange1 As String
    Dim myrange2 As String
    myrange1 = A1
    myrange2 = a2
    Range(myrange1).Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sample generator").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sample generator").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
        "X2"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sample generator").Sort
        .SetRange Range(myrange1)
        .Header = xlNo
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    Range(myrange2).Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sample generator").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sample generator").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
        "X4"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sample generator").Sort
        .SetRange Range(myrange2)
        .Header = xlNo
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

Thanks!

Comment: Go on then...don't keep us in suspense.  How did the code not work?

Comment: I'm thinking..... `variable not defined`?  Wrap `A1` & `A2` in square brackets, but then you'll only get the value of A1 and not a reference to it.  Try changing `myRange1` to a `Range` rather than a `String` and `Set` it as it's an object...

Comment: I would go with `myrange1 = "A1"`

Comment: hi Darren, I actually went back with the code I'm playing with, and I somehow dim'd myrange1 and 2 as range, not string. I as well tried brackets and no brackets, but somehow won't make it run. I probably should bother as well what error message is being displayed, so thanks for the tip. Anyway, I had my answer with Japeed's sample code. Tried playing a bit with it, and it somehow worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In A1 you have a formula that creates the string "X1:X2"; in A2 you have a formula that creates the string "Y1:Y2".

You want to sort X1:X2 in an ascending manner then sort the range Y1:Y2 in an ascending manner.

```
Option Explicit

Sub mySort()
    Dim myrange1 As String, myrange2 As String

    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sample generator")

        myrange1 = .Cells(1, "A").Value2
        myrange2 = .Cells(2, "A").Value2

        With .Range(myrange1)
            .Cells.Sort Key1:=.Cells(1), Order1:=xlAscending, _
                        Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlNo
        End With

        With .Range(myrange2)
            .Cells.Sort Key1:=.Cells(1), Order1:=xlAscending, _
                        Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlNo
        End With

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Why **.Value2** ?

Comment: Why not? It's infinitesimally faster and the strings contain neither currency or date information that would be gained from .Value.

Comment: Thanks so much! I was able to make it work after playing after a few tries with your provided code. Not sure why, but I as well tried .value, but it doesn't sort the second set. With .value2, this works, so I sticked with it instead. I also learned some used text, such as .cells and .value2, though I can't understand how the .Cells(1) work since it only enumerates a single digit inside cells. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The way you have written it:

```
Sub Sort()
    Dim myrange1 As String
    Dim myrange2 As String
    myrange1 = A1
    myrange2 = a2
```

`A1` and `a2` are variables. And below in your code `Range(myrange1).Select`, they are probably intended to be strings, as far as you are mentioning here "ranges in A1 and A2 separately".

Thus, try something like this:

```
myrange1 = "A1"
myrange2 = "a2"
```

Then `Range(myrange1).Select` would run quite well.

In general, read these two to make your code a bit better:

- [MSDN Option Explicit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/option-explicit-statement)
- [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

And then try to refactor the whole code.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! The references were as well helpful in adding knowledge to my basic VBA understanding and in reducing some code typing. Not sure why, but I still was not able to make it run properly. I tried playing around a bit with Jeeped's provided answer, and was able to get it right after a few tries. I truly appreciate though your references. Thanks!